# WinServer2016 - Access Denied when adding or changing a GPO

Tags: active-directory, permissions, group-policy, windows-server-2016, sysvol

I have inherited a network whose GPOs are damaged, the SYSVOL folder shows signs of tampering with the NTFS permissions and folder structure manually, and I am unable to add/edit any GPOs, I receive an ["Access Denied" error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxljW.png) and the only entry in eventvwr I can find looks like an app crash for the mmc plugin. From timestamps it is clear this hasn't worked for 4+years.

- I have performed a [D2 and D4 restore](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/5f2c91b9-2a36-ddf9-ea85-8377cd55811c) separately, this did not resolve the issue. [auth restore img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOaAW.png)
- I have confirmed delegation permissions on the domain were modified, I reset them to default. [Domain permission delegation img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB7V9.png)
- Group Policy Object permissions are still modified from original, couldn't figure out how to reset these to default: [Group Policy Object Permissions img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bZO5.png)
- There are no existing GPOs I have to worry about.
- There are 3 Server 2016 DCs.
- I attempted to add NTFS permissions to C:\Windows\Sysvol and sub folders individually to give my domain admin account full control. Still no change.
- gpupdate seems to work fine, I just can't add or edit policies from any DC

At this time I cannot create or edit GPOs, but client machines gpupdate successfully. What else can I do to be able to edit GPOs again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this in the future. Some numbskull renamed the sysvol folder on the PDC... fixing that fixed everything else.